# How to access XAML page's BindingContext from within BlazorWebView control in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, blazor-hybrid

The razor page is being hosted in the BlazorWebView control on the XAML page.  I would like to be able to get to the view model I have assigned to the BindingContext of said XAML from within the razor page.

DaySummaryPage.XAML

```
<BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html" x:Name="bWebviewAdventureLocMain" >
    <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type razor:DaySummaryPage}" />
    </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
</BlazorWebView>
```

DaySummaryPage.razor

```
@code {
 // Access DaySummaryPage.XAML's BindingContext
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no `BindingContext` in Blazor. You can refer to the Component parameters part in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#component-parameters), and check [Binding with component parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#binding-with-component-parameters).

You can refer to [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/874348/documentation-example-missing-for-maui-x-blazor.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, that answers a question I had on how to make that work.  Unfortunately, it is too limited to only be set once on initialization.  I need the same functionality BindingContext provides to XAML, ie two way binding.  I have created a class that the .razor listens to for events for when the XAML file back button is triggered as well as when the page is presented again (but not initialized).